# Destination multitype text file

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I need to export data from my database to a text file. Problem is text files would be:

```
"1   99999    AHDHADL" <br />
"2   CL EALDA ADLFALDFAH 99999" <br />
"1   77777    ADFJASDFH" <br />
"2   CL DFHAJSDF ADKJFHASKDJF 77777" <br />
```

I don't know how can I create a file with two different types of row. Always, I have a type of row "1" and then row "2". Row 2 is a detail from row previous. Other times, I import a multitype file from database but to export I don't know.

Comment: Your question is unclear..show us your attempt..

Comment: Could you show/explain to us: 1. you data model 2. the schema for the file you are creating 3. your attempts so far?

Comment: Ok, 1. My data model, I have a client table and other table with risk for each client. The schema for the file it's first row detail client and second row risk for this client. Each row start with a code 1(client), 2(risks), then ID client, and finally detail information for client and risks.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible for the standard SSIS components. When exporting, you'd define a Flat File output with a given set of columns. There's no way to deviate from this.

Even if you would concatenate all values to a single text column (using the Derived Columns transformation) and join the overview and detail rows, I don;t think you could guarantee order (ie the details row following the correct header row).